# Android Google Maps API - cannot resolve "location.setLatitude()"

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a location and set latitude and longitude, but when I write

```
location.setLatitude
```

I'm getting

> cannot resolve symbol

error. Anyone can help?

```
Location location = new Location("");
location.setLatitude(0.0d);
```

If I change code like this:

```
Location location = new Location("")
     .setLatitude(0.0d)
```

I'm getting error

> Incopatible types. ;
>   Required: android.location.Location ;
>   Found: void

Edit: Here's the class. It's literally code from Google tutorial. I deleted some unnecessary parts, and added few i needed.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private GoogleMap mMap;
private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;

// The entry points to the Places API.
private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;
private PlaceDetectionClient mPlaceDetectionClient;

// The entry point to the Fused Location Provider.
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

// A default location (Sydney, Australia) and default zoom to use when location permission is
// not granted.
private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(49.656639, 19.636917);
private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

// The geographical location where the device is currently located. That is, the last-known
// location retrieved by the Fused Location Provider.
private Location mLastKnownLocation;


// Keys for storing activity state.
private static final String KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position";
private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

// Used for selecting the current place.
private static final int M_MAX_ENTRIES = 5;
private String[] mLikelyPlaceNames;
private String[] mLikelyPlaceAddresses;
private String[] mLikelyPlaceAttributions;
private LatLng[] mLikelyPlaceLatLngs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
        mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
    }

    // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Construct a GeoDataClient.
    mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(this, null);

    // Construct a PlaceDetectionClient.
    mPlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this, null);

    // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    // Build the map.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

/**
 * Saves the state of the map when the activity is paused.
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (mMap != null) {
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, mMap.getCameraPosition());
        outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mLastKnownLocation);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}




LatLng centPoint = new LatLng(49.656639, 19.636917);
int kolStrefa = Color.argb(40, 255, 0, 0);

Location location = new Location("");
location.setLatitude(0.0d);  //Cannot resolve symbol 




@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    // Use a custom info window adapter to handle multiple lines of text in the
    // info window contents.


    // Prompt the user for permission.
    getLocationPermission();

    // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
    updateLocationUI();

    // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
    getDeviceLocation();

    CircleOptions strefa = new CircleOptions()
            .center(centPoint)
            .radius(200)
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .fillColor(kolStrefa);

    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(strefa);

}




double distance = mLastKnownLocation.distanceTo(krzCent);
/**
 * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
 */
private void getDeviceLocation() {
    /*
     * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
     * cases when a location is not available.
     */
    try {
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                        mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e)  {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}


/**
 * Prompts the user for permission to use the device location.
 */
private void getLocationPermission() {
    /*
     * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
     * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
     * onRequestPermissionsResult.
     */
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
}

/**
 * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            }
        }
    }
    updateLocationUI();
}

/**
 * Prompts the user to select the current place from a list of likely places, and shows the
 * current place on the map - provided the user has granted location permission.
 */
private void showCurrentPlace() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
        // Get the likely places - that is, the businesses and other points of interest that
        // are the best match for the device's current location.
        @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission") final
        Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> placeResult =
                mPlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(null);
        placeResult.addOnCompleteListener
                (new OnCompleteListener<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                            PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();

                            // Set the count, handling cases where less than 5 entries are returned.
                            int count;
                            if (likelyPlaces.getCount() < M_MAX_ENTRIES) {
                                count = likelyPlaces.getCount();
                            } else {
                                count = M_MAX_ENTRIES;
                            }

                            int i = 0;
                            mLikelyPlaceNames = new String[count];
                            mLikelyPlaceAddresses = new String[count];
                            mLikelyPlaceAttributions = new String[count];
                            mLikelyPlaceLatLngs = new LatLng[count];

                            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                                // Build a list of likely places to show the user.
                                mLikelyPlaceNames[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName();
                                mLikelyPlaceAddresses[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                                        .getAddress();
                                mLikelyPlaceAttributions[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                                        .getAttributions();
                                mLikelyPlaceLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng();

                                i++;
                                if (i > (count - 1)) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            // Release the place likelihood buffer, to avoid memory leaks.
                            likelyPlaces.release();

                            // Show a dialog offering the user the list of likely places, and add a
                            // marker at the selected place.
                            openPlacesDialog();

                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // The user has not granted permission.
        Log.i(TAG, "The user did not grant location permission.");

        // Add a default marker, because the user hasn't selected a place.
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("DEF")
                .position(mDefaultLocation)
                .snippet("DEFfd"));

        // Prompt the user for permission.
        getLocationPermission();
    }
}

/**
 * Displays a form allowing the user to select a place from a list of likely places.
 */
private void openPlacesDialog() {
    // Ask the user to choose the place where they are now.
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // The "which" argument contains the position of the selected item.
            LatLng markerLatLng = mLikelyPlaceLatLngs[which];
            String markerSnippet = mLikelyPlaceAddresses[which];
            if (mLikelyPlaceAttributions[which] != null) {
                markerSnippet = markerSnippet + "\n" + mLikelyPlaceAttributions[which];
            }

            // Add a marker for the selected place, with an info window
            // showing information about that place.
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(mLikelyPlaceNames[which])
                    .position(markerLatLng)
                    .snippet(markerSnippet));

            // Position the map's camera at the location of the marker.
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerLatLng,
                    DEFAULT_ZOOM));
        }
    };

    // Display the dialog.

}

/**
 * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
 */
private void updateLocationUI() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            mLastKnownLocation = null;
            getLocationPermission();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e)  {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: is it android.location.Location ?

Comment: Yup, android.location.Location, I'm working on maps activity

Comment: Did you import this in your class file where you are writing those lines?

Comment: Of course, It's like I can create Location but can't set latitude and longitude this way

Comment: Try android studio => File -> invalidate caches / restart.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. And AndroidStudio says, that "import android.location.Location;" is unused.

Comment: can you kindly post the whole class please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should try to create a completely new class and create this Location there to see if the error lies within the rest of the code.

And finally, 
`Location location = new Location("").setLatitude(0.0d);` will not work because you first create your Location and then instantly set the latitude. Java thinks that you want to assign the return value of `#setLatitude` to the variable (which of course is not possible since it returns void).

Comment: I created whole new project to try it and the problem is still the same. I can declare "Location location = new Location("") ", but when I want to set latitude I get "cannot resolve symbol" error on "setLatitude()". And when I start to type "location.[...]" in drop-down menu I have only "Creator()" and "ClassLoaderCreator".

Comment: @Arcer Then I think you really imported the wrong Location somehow (although the methods you mentioned should be there because Location extends Parcelable). Try `android.location.Location location = new android.location.Location("")` instead.

Comment: I declared it the way you suggested, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Still, I can create it, but can't call "setLatitude()".

Comment: I think now I got it! You try to operate with the object outside of a method. Try to put `location.setLatitude(0.0d);` into the `onCreate` method. In Java all operations must be inside a method. You can only assign variables outside of them (operations involving a `=`). If this works for you I'll cast my post into an answer. It would be kind of you if you accept the answer and thereby close the question.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you, I didn't think it was that simple!